# Makefile rule to conditionally run script and then copy files

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile, I'm trying to create a rule that will build RPMs if they don't already exist (based on looking at particular directory) otherwise just copy those RPMs to some other directory.

Essentially what I'd like to do is:

```
if somedir/build does NOT has RPMs:
  somedir/build.sh

cp -R somedir/build/* destination
```

I've been toying with using `$(shell if [[ -d somedir/build ]] ....)` but not having much luck.

Comment: If that directory doesn't have *any* RPMs? Can you build individual RPMs via make or just run a single "gotta build 'em all" script? What target or prerequisite deals with your RPMs at the moment? Is there one?

Comment: If you're using make why not make the rpms part of the dependency chain? How do you determine which rpms need to be built in the shell script?

Comment: @EtanReisner so the 'somedir/build.sh' builds RPMs. I don't have a target depending on this yet.

Comment: @user657267 i determine if rpms need to be built based on if any exist in a build directory. See my update for what I have working now.

Comment: I second @user657267's suggestion. Drop your script and build RPMS via make when you need them (doing this correctly for all the specfile dependencies is tricky and requires some manual labor but is doable, I've done it at work). Barring that what you have is basically the best you can get. You could make directory creation an order-only prerequisite and pull it out of the recipe body if you wanted to but that isn't a big deal. Also you don't care about the count just `!= 0` so a glob + loop is likely faster. `for f in somedir/build/*.rpm; do found=1; break; done; if [ -n "$found" ]; ...`

Comment: The other project doesn't use make but does use rpm specfiles. Anyhow, I think the snippet used in the 'update' will suffice for now.

Comment: @EtanReisner I respectfully disagree that this is the best he can get.  He can "get much better" using sentinel files correctly, as in my answer.

Comment: Is this a fixed list of RPMs (so you can hardcode the list into the Makefile) or is the set of RPMs that `build.sh` will produce unpredictable? That really isn't a use case `make` was designed to support.

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

```
someproject_rpms:
    @if [[ -d somedir/build ]] ; then \
        count=$$(find somedir/build -name "*.rpm" -type f | wc -l); \
        if [[ $$count -eq 0 ]]; then \
            $$(cd somedir && ./build.sh); \
        fi \
    else \
        $$(cd somedir && ./build.sh); \
    fi; \
    find somedir/build -name "*.rpm" -type f -exec cp {} somedestination \;
```

Not the prettiest, but it works.

Comment: do you want to copy directory structure to destination, or flat copy .rpms.  Your question does the former.  Your answer does the latter.  So your answer is not technically correct.  Which is it do you want?

Comment: The question shows I need to copy the RPMs to a destination (cp -R somedir/build/* destination), which is what I am also showing in the answer, right?

Comment: No your answer does not copy directory structure - it copies all files flat to the destination, without copying directories.  My answer also does that in fact, but that's because I followed your answer as my guess as to what you really want.

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed the distinction. Yes, I only want to copy the files, not the directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should use so-called "sentinel" files. These are empty files, that are used only for their timestamp, and the timestamp signifies the completion of some action, typically creating a bunch of other files, whose names we may or may not know.  The two files named `rpms` are the sentinel files, and here is your solution `Makefile`:

```
destination/rpms: somedir/build/rpms Makefile
    find $(<D) -name *.rpm -exec cp {} $(@D) \;
    touch $@

somedir/build/rpms: $(PACKEES) Makefile
    somedir/build.sh
    touch $@
```

`PACKEES` right now is empty, but you should set it to be all the files you want to have packed into any of your rpms, in other words, all the files that `build.sh` reads.  If you insist on using one `build.sh` script to build all your rpms at once (which is not a good idea), the above *is* the best you are going to get :)

Comment: While I fully agree with this *concept* as a better concept then what I gave in my comments. I think this implementation is not, in fact, better. It doesn't rebuild the RPMS if the RPMs are deleted but no source files change (unless you include them in `$(PACKEES)` which you can certainly do). It also requires manual keeping of a list which will, if mis-kept, not build when you expect it might (a failure mode which the simpler build-if-missing test does not have). There's a reason I spent a fair bit of time scripting a way to extract requirement files from my spec files. =)

Comment: @Etan, OK so we politely disagree on philosophy here.  I don't allow arbitrary deletions in my build system. To me, build system is a state machine, where only certain actions are allowed: touching sources, and making targets, including clean.  But not deleting by hand. If the user does that, they are on their own.  That is what I say in my manuals. Second, I view "manual keeping of lists" as a plus in fact, not a minus. IMHO, all lists of files, should be explicitly declared by the user, if possible, not found by wildcards or some such.  Of course, declared in one place only, not repeated.

Comment: I almost completely agree with that philosophy and I've been working hard at getting build stuff at work to the point where everything just works and can be reliably rebuilt (though CI seems to love to want fully clean builds every time, presumably because most people don't get this right). This, I think somewhat clearly, isn't that sort of situation though. In another context I'm sure we could spend quite a while discussing all of this quite fruitfully I imagine.